# Are the Arduino Micro, Mini, etc plug'n play?

Tags: arduino-micro

Also, what about the micro/nano/mini arduinos? Are they easily plug'n'play like the uno?
(This is an edit from another of my questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones that have a USB connector are plug-and-play with a USB host. The ones that don't need a USB-to-UART bridge.

Comment: What's a UART? I'm totally new to this. Also, do the arduinos I mentioned have breadboard-style connectors like the uno?

Comment: A UART is what implements the "serial" connection. They come with bare plated holes, so some basic soldering experience is required.